# Cannot connect using tnsnames.ora but can connect by substituting its details

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I'm setting up a minimal Oracle Instant Client on a non-Oracle Linux host from zip files (as per https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/apd.htm#SQPUG157) and have installed

```
instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
```

(note: no tnsping is available).

I've added the following environment variables:

```
ORACLE_SID=prod; export ORACLE_SID
ORACLE_HOME=/local/share/bin/oracle_client/instantclient_12_1; export ORACLE_HOME
SQLPLUS=$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus; export SQLPLUS
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
TNS_ADMIN=/local/share/oracle/network; export TNS_ADMIN
```

The $TNS_ADMIN/tnsnames.ora file is provided by an Oracle host (I cannot change it), is readable from this non-Oracle host, and contains no syntax errors (it is in use by Oracle hosts).  The specific entry looks much like this:

```
PROD.DOMAIN =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = prod.domain)(PORT = 1234))
  )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = prod)
 )
)
```

That said, I cannot connect on the command line using the preferred method for us:

```
$SQLPLUS user@prod
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Dec 14 14:45:22 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

suggesting that tnsnames is not being found or parsed or... ? I believe I have everything in place as per "Connecting to a Database with SQL*Plus Instant Client" in the referenced document at the top.

Note that I can connect if I use the host name itself:

```
$SQLPLUS user@\"//prod.domain:1235/prod\"
```

or the details from tnsnames itself (proving good syntax):

```
$SQLPLUS user@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=prod.domain)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=prod)))"
```

Any ideas?

My current workaround is the third method using Perl to parse tnsnames into a set of one-liners and grep for the instance I want but it'd be nice to know why this isn't working and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: The entry is `PROD.DOMAIN`, you're trying `@prod` ?

Comment: Yes, this format works presumably because service name is "prod".  All other instances in tnsnames can be referenced in this way.

Comment: Check file /local/share/oracle/network/sqlnet.ora. If default_domain is DOMAIN then you can skip it. Otherwise you have to specify it.

Comment: sqlnet.ora is not referenced in the Oracle doc and there is no such file provided for me by the Oracle DBAs in /local/share/oracle/network (making me believe it shouldn't be required but I am researching it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Wernfried Domscheit for pointing me to sqlnet.ora.  This file was not referenced in the documentation I was using so I had no idea it existed.  After visiting an Oracle host and finding the file in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin, I copied it to $TNS_ADMIN dir and minimized it through testing to the one setting (no others were needed) Wernfried referenced:

```
# this setting = my local domain
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = DOMAIN
```

and my preferred connection method of

```
$SQLPLUS user@prod
```

succeeded.  I will speak with the Oracle DBAs about this file and it's proper inclusion in this shared dir.